# Regex Match Html Tag and Inner Html Pattern

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I've scraped a web page and I'm trying to extract data from a `td` that has no class or ids. Let's say I have the following html:

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>The Harsh Face of Mother Nature</td>
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
</table>
```

I'm trying to do a `preg_match`:

```
$title = preg_match("\(>Title)(.*?)(?=<\/td\>{2})\", $html);
```

My pattern starts with `>Title` and the ending is the 2nd occurrence of `</td>`.

I've been working with https://regex101.com/ to try to figure this out, but regex is really tough! Especially with the obscure stuff I'm trying to accomplish. Any help, please? Thanks!

(edit below:)
The goal is to get a sting like: `</td><td>The Harsh Face of Mother Nature` then to do another preg match to remove the first part and have the final product of `The Harsh Face of Mother Nature`

Comment: are you ok with parsing html files with regex? What would be your expected output?

Comment: I put an edit at bottom to explain my goal/expected output.

Comment: What are you trying to capture? Just two td tags or more than two? Do you know forsure the first contains title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try another technique:** `>Title.*?(?=<td>)<td>\K.*?(?=<\/td>)`

```
$re = "/>Title.*?(?=<td>)<td>\\K.*?(?=<\\/td>)/s";
$str = "<table> \n <tr>\n <td>Title</td>\n <td>The Harsh Face of Mother Nature</td>\n <td>The Harsh Face of Mother Nature</td>\n </tr>\n .\n .\n .\n</table>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW5yO6/5)

Comment: This seems to work in the regex101, thank you. Sadly though, I have a problem making my $crawler object a string, so I cannot apply this method until I have that problem solved. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267492/domcrawler-not-dumping-data-properly-for-parsing)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex in preg_match or preg_match_all

```
>Title.*?<\/td>.*?<td>\K.*?(?=<\/td>)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rW5yO6/3)

```
$re = "/>Title.*?<\\/td>.*?<td>\\K.*?(?=<\\/td>)/s";
$str = "<table> \n <tr>\n <td>Title</td>\n <td>The Harsh Face of Mother Nature</td>\n </tr>\n .\n .\n .\n</table>";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex     `.*\<table\>\s*\<tr\>\s*\s*\<td\>title\<\/td>\s*\<td\>((\w*\s*\w*)*)<\/td>.*` It will capture in the first group the content of the `<td>` tag that follows the `<td>title</td>`, which comes after a `<table>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

use js n-th child property to get it

```
$( "table tr td:nth-child(2)" )
```

Comment: I can't, the web page has many, many tables, and each table is filled dynamically, so no knowing how many rows are in it.